# Easy way to bind dataset to input fields with webforms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

I'm used to be working with MVC .NET and there it is fairly easy to create a table with multiple rows and columns with input fields both to display them and post them back to the server by letting the server identifying the POST-data with my custom Model.

Now I have a custom grid view made of HTML, CSS and Javascript with dynamic number of rows, number of columns is set.

My question: How can I in an easy way name the input fields or somehow display them dynamic so that they are easy to send back to the server via postback?

Something like a gridview would be nice but I can't use it because I have multiple header-rows and multiple footer-rows.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the editing contained to a single row, or is it the entire table?

Comment: Entire table. In the visual content headers and footers isn't edited. So it is pretty simple raw data. X nr of rows and 8 columns that is editable.